# ca-certificates-java fails when trying to install openjdk-6-jre

Tags: 10.10, server, installation, java, openjdk

I use a VPS with Ubuntu Server 10.10 x64. I want to use Java and run the command `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre` but it fails because the installation encounted errors while processing `ca-certificates-java`.

I have tried to install the failed package with:

`sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java`

How can I solve this?

I have run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` but I get the same errors after that.

I have also installed Ubuntu Server x64 on a VirtualBox, but the two Ubuntu Server 10.10 has different kernel versions (**2.6.35** on VirtualBox and **2.6.18** on my VPS). And on VirtualBox I can install Jetty without any problems.

---

The VPS is a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 10.10 x64, the first command I was running was `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre`.

When I run `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java` I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates-java is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Here I press `Y` then I get this message:

```
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20100412) ...
creating /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts...
  error adding brasil.gov.br/brasil.gov.br.crt
  error adding cacert.org/cacert.org.crt
  error adding debconf.org/ca.crt
  error adding gouv.fr/cert_igca_dsa.crt
  error adding gouv.fr/cert_igca_rsa.crt
  error adding mozilla/ABAecom_=sub.__Am._Bankers_Assn.=_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/AOL_Time_Warner_Root_Certification_Authority_1.crt
  error adding mozilla/AOL_Time_Warner_Root_Certification_Authority_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/AddTrust_Low-Value_Services_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/AddTrust_Public_Services_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/AddTrust_Qualified_Certificates_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/America_Online_Root_Certification_Authority_1.crt
  error adding mozilla/America_Online_Root_Certification_Authority_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/COMODO_Certification_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/Camerfirma_Chambers_of_Commerce_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/Camerfirma_Global_Chambersign_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/Certplus_Class_2_Primary_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Certum_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Comodo_AAA_Services_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/Comodo_Secure_Services_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/Comodo_Trusted_Services_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/DST_ACES_CA_X6.crt
  error adding mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt
  error adding mozilla/DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/DigiNotar_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Digital_Signature_Trust_Co._Global_CA_1.crt
  error adding mozilla/Digital_Signature_Trust_Co._Global_CA_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Digital_Signature_Trust_Co._Global_CA_3.crt
  error adding mozilla/Digital_Signature_Trust_Co._Global_CA_4.crt
  error adding mozilla/Entrust.net_Global_Secure_Personal_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Entrust.net_Global_Secure_Server_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Entrust.net_Secure_Personal_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/Equifax_Secure_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Equifax_Secure_Global_eBusiness_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Equifax_Secure_eBusiness_CA_1.crt
  error adding mozilla/Equifax_Secure_eBusiness_CA_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Firmaprofesional_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/GTE_CyberTrust_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/GeoTrust_Global_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/GeoTrust_Global_CA_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/GeoTrust_Universal_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/GeoTrust_Universal_CA_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/IPS_CLASE1_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/IPS_CLASE3_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/IPS_CLASEA1_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/IPS_CLASEA3_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/IPS_Chained_CAs_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/IPS_Servidores_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/IPS_Timestamping_root.crt
  error adding mozilla/NetLock_Business_=Class_B=_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/NetLock_Express_=Class_C=_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/NetLock_Notary_=Class_A=_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/NetLock_Qualified_=Class_QA=_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/Network_Solutions_Certificate_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.crt
  error adding mozilla/RSA_Root_Certificate_1.crt
  error adding mozilla/RSA_Security_1024_v3.crt
  error adding mozilla/RSA_Security_2048_v3.crt
  error adding mozilla/SecureTrust_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Secure_Global_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Security_Communication_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Sonera_Class_1_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Starfield_Class_2_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/StartCom_Certification_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/StartCom_Ltd..crt
  error adding mozilla/SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.crt
  error adding mozilla/SwissSign_Platinum_CA_-_G2.crt
  error adding mozilla/SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Swisscom_Root_CA_1.crt
  error adding mozilla/TC_TrustCenter__Germany__Class_2_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/TC_TrustCenter__Germany__Class_3_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/TDC_Internet_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/TDC_OCES_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_1.crt
  error adding mozilla/TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Taiwan_GRCA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Thawte_Personal_Basic_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Thawte_Personal_Freemail_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Thawte_Personal_Premium_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Thawte_Server_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Thawte_Time_Stamping_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/UTN-USER_First-Network_Applications.crt
  error adding mozilla/UTN_DATACorp_SGC_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/UTN_USERFirst_Email_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/ValiCert_Class_1_VA.crt
  error adding mozilla/ValiCert_Class_2_VA.crt
  error adding mozilla/VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_2_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_2_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_2_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_4_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Class_4_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_RSA_Secure_Server_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Verisign_Time_Stamping_Authority_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/Visa_International_Global_Root_2.crt
  error adding mozilla/Visa_eCommerce_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/WellsSecure_Public_Root_Certificate_Authority.crt
  error adding mozilla/Wells_Fargo_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/XRamp_Global_CA_Root.crt
  error adding mozilla/beTRUSTed_Root_CA-Baltimore_Implementation.crt
  error adding mozilla/beTRUSTed_Root_CA.crt
  error adding mozilla/beTRUSTed_Root_CA_-_Entrust_Implementation.crt
  error adding mozilla/beTRUSTed_Root_CA_-_RSA_Implementation.crt
  error adding mozilla/thawte_Primary_Root_CA.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_ca1_pem.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_ca2_pem.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_ca3_pem.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_ocspklasa2_pem.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_ocspklasa3_pem.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_pca2_pem.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_pca3_pem.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_rootca_pem.crt
  error adding signet.pl/signet_tsa1_pem.crt
  error adding spi-inc.org/spi-ca-2003.crt
  error adding spi-inc.org/spi-cacert-2008.crt
  error adding telesec.de/deutsche-telekom-root-ca-2.crt
failed (VM used: java-6-openjdk).
dpkg: error processing ca-certificates-java (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates-java
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

**Update**

I also get a problem when running `java -version`:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

My VPS had 128MB of Memory, I changed to 256MB but got the same problem. Then I changed to 512MB and got the same problem.

I found a related post on a forum: [Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1174123)
And I tried:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get --reinstall install openjdk-6-jre
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But I got the same problem, even when I'm using 512MB of Memory.

Any suggestions?

---

**Update 2:**

I have now created a new VPS with 512MB and Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS x64 and run these commands:

sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre

But I got the same error messages. If I do the same thing in VirtualBox everything works fine.

Comment: Can you paste in the errors?  Is this server 64-bit also?

Comment: @jgbelacqua: Yes, this is also x64 and I have posted the error messages now.

Comment: Related bug: [package ca-certificates-java 20080712ubuntu2 failed to install/upgrade: subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/289091)

Comment: Can you post the output of this command?

    sudo keytool -v -importcert -trustcacerts -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -noprompt -storepass 'changeit' -alias brasil.gov.br -file /usr/share/ca-certificates/brasil.gov.br/brasil.gov.br.crt

Comment: Yes, it's the same error I get when running `java -version`: `Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is obviously due to Java actually not working inside OpenVZ/Virtuozzo due to its different way of virtualization compared to VirtualBox. It's about JVM always trying to allocate more memory than available in VM and requires some command line options. Actually using Java inside a VPS (based on OpenVZ/Virtuozzo) is a neverending pain. Had to realize this on trying to install Zimbra in a VPS and there are plenty of sites dedicated to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

This problem because of using OpenVZ/Virtuozzo with memory limit = 256 . 
I solved it by increasing memory limit for OpenVZ/Virtuozzo from 256Mb to 512Mb.

by these commands:

```
vzctl set 100 --vmguarpages $((256 * 256)) --save &&
vzctl set 100 --privvmpages $((256 * 512)) --save &&
vzctl set 100 --swappages $((256 * 1024)) --save &&
vzctl restart 100
```