# How can I install other applications after a failed installation using apt-get?

Tags: 10.10, server, apt, openjdk

I have a VPS with Ubuntu Server 10.10 x64.

I tried to install Java using `apt-get install openjdk-6-jre` but that fails, see [ca-certificates-java fails to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28943/ca-certificates-java-fails-to-install).

Now I would like to install PHP with `sudo apt-get install nginx php5-fpm php-apc php5-pgsql php5-suhosin` but that also fails, with the same error message as I had with Java. Why is that? How can I install other applications now after the installation of Java has failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install other applications until you resolve the problem with `ca-certificates-java`. `apt-get` won't let you keep any packages in an unconfigured state.

If you are not able to resolve the problem (you should - just google the error message Java gives you), force removal of the package:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst.backup
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates-java
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a broken *ca-certificates-java* package. Because the apt error says:

```
1 not fully installed or removed.
```

First try to remove it with: `dpkg -r ca-certificates-java`

and reinstall it with apt: `apt-get install ca-certificates-java`

if other Dependencies are not resolvable, try `apt-get -f install` to resolve failed dependencies.

Comment: `dpkg -r ca-certificates-java` returns this error message: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of ca-certificates-java:
 openjdk-6-jre-headless depends on ca-certificates-java.
dpkg: error processing ca-certificates-java (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing`

Comment: And your other suggested commands just returns the same error messages as I had before.

Comment: Try a force install of the ca-certificates-java package:
`dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/ca-certificates-java`
and take a look to the install status:
`dpkg -s ca-certificates-java`

Comment: The command `dpkg -i --force-all ...` gives this result: `dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ca-certificates-java (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ca-certificates-java`

Comment: The command `dpkg -s ca-certificates-java` gives this result: `Package: ca-certificates-java
Status: install ok half-configured
Priority: optional
Section: java
Installed-Size: 252
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 20100406ubuntu1
Depends: ca-certificates (>= 20090814), openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b16-1.6.1-2) | java6-runtime-headless
Recommends: libnss3-1d
Conffiles:
 /etc/default/cacerts 0ded97abeff69c2362939e2e881e214a
 /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore 84ae89a338475ccc602f9b0128a124f3`

Comment: `Description: Common CA certificates (JKS keystore)
 This package uses the hooks of the ca-certificates package to update the
 cacerts JKS keystore used for many java runtimes.
Original-Maintainer: OpenJDK Team <openjdk@lists.launchpad.net>`

Comment: `dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/ca-certificates-java_20100412_all.deb` (that's the package name in case of debian 6 - you have to type the correct **filename of the package** - be sure: `ls -la /var/cache/apt/archives/ca-*`).

If that takes no effect, try `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates-java`